# User defined functions-for loops (JAVA)

Tags: java

My question is straight.
I have made a simple app in neatbeans in which when I click a button the x coordinates of the text say a '@' keeps changing by 20.
heres the code:-

```
int x;

private void wActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                  
    x=x+20;       
    q.setLocation(x, 0);    
}
```

this code simply moves the jlabel ( q ) to the right by 20 coordinates each time i click the jbutton ( w ).
now what i want is that when i click the button only ONCE then the position of the JLabel should keep increasing its x coordinate by 20 untill it has reached a specific x coordinate say 200.
i tried using for loops :-

```
private void wActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    for(x=0;x<201;x=x+20)
    {
        q.setlocation(x,0);
    }  
}
```

but with this when I click the button, the jlabel directly moves to 200 x coordinate without stopping after every 20 coordinates...please help..
Regards,
Slinger

Comment: and for how long should it stop, before moving forward again? Did you try using sleep()?

Comment: Ask yourself: how fast do I expect the label to move? Where is in my code a parameter which controls the speed?

Comment: hola,
i ant it to stop for 1 sec after each time it moves ..remember..i want it to reach coordinte (200,0) while the x coordinate is increasing by 20 in every 1 second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above is that Swing is calling your incrementer and only performing a refresh once your incrementing function has completed. Instead you need to start up a separate thread to perform this animation and let Swing update after each increment.

Check out [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class. Here's [a tutorial on SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: thats right Brian...but its goes over my head :(
can i get a example of something?? for beter understanding?